# When do we need <auth-constraint> element empty?

Tags: java

I wanna know when I leave empty  element empty in my Deployment Descriptor file then it does not grant any role to access
But when do i need it DD where all the time anyone role must access my web page.
In which situation I do not need no role to be accessed?

Answer (score 0):

auth-constraint is empty -  implying no one will have access to the resource, so with it, its quite clear that when you dont want anybody to a access a particular resource you can go for an empty value.